# Highcharts 9.1.1 export from fullscreen with print option- throw error on browser console Uncaught TypeError: a.hasAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, requirejs

while export Highcharts V9.1.1 from fullscreen with option Print throw error on console.

```
accessibility.src.js:431 Uncaught TypeError: a.hasAttribute is not a function
    at accessibility.src.js:431
    at NodeList.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at l (accessibility.src.js:430)
    at l (accessibility.src.js:436)
    at l (accessibility.src.js:436)
    at l (accessibility.src.js:436)
    at describeSeries (accessibility.src.js:3494)
    at accessibility.src.js:4096
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at b.onChartRender (accessibility.src.js:4091)
```

and try again to without fullscreen export button then we see option **Exit from Fullscreen** where the chart already exited from fullscreen.

Here is JSfiddle Url-https://jsfiddle.net/aoLg8m1y/1/

view chart in fullscreen  then export using Print then open browser console. will see error.
after this step click export button will fullscreen option not reset and still say exit from full screen.

as I found this issue with jquery plugin highcharts.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bug, I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow this thread: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/16126

Thanks for sharing it!